# How to programmatically reject (hang up) incoming call on Android in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, phone-call, delphi-10-seattle

A Java solution is not a problem:

```java
public boolean killCall(Context context) {
    try {
        // Get the boring old TelephonyManager
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Get the getITelephony() method
        Class classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
        Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

        // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
        methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

        // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
        Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

        // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
        Class telephonyInterfaceClass =  
                Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
        Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

        // Invoke endCall()
        methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

    } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
        Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **" + ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**But how to make the same solution in Delphi?**

Unfortunately I did not find any a guide to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but why don't you use the java code ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Because he's doing his development in Delphi and not Java?

Comment: I need it in one application that is written (and must be) in Delphi.

Comment: have not heard of apps written with delphi running on android, Android is for the large part, Java, DalvikVM or ART runtime based.

Comment: @t0mm13b Now you have.  Delphi is cross-platform and can compile to Win, iOS, OSX, and Android.

Comment: If you can read Java, then it should not be a problem to translate it to Delphi?

Comment: I do not know how to convert that part from  // Get the getITelephony() method

Comment: @t0mm13b Delphi includes a considerable library of cross-platform wrappers for the various underlying APIs.  The question is valid as it is asking (implicitly) whether this behaviour is currently supported in those wrappers.  Ideally one wants to use cross-platform components where possible before resorting to importing the platform-specific API calls (and the resulting untidyness of conditional compilation directives, duplication of work for various platforms, etc).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you asked around on Embarcadero's forums? Looked at code samples?

Comment: Find out information about the call is not a problem. That's all resolved. But I never finished reading how to get to the object ITelephony.

Although there is a link to a forum in which to address this issue, but references planted in this forum are invalid. There was nothing else I could find.

Comment: [Link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105837) to forum

Comment: Have you tried Brian Long's solutions? blong.com It helped me a lot when I was using Delphi to develop for Android and found it fell short. Also check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcuYc7F0lIU

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is currently not possible in Delphi code directly, due to a known bug in Delphi's Android Bridge framework:

[QC #120233 Android Jlang_Class interface is missing 19 methods](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=120233)

[QP #RSP-12686 Android Jlang_Class interface is missing 19 methods](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12686)

`getDeclaredMethod()` is one of the missing methods, and without it you cannot gain access to the `ITelephony` interface.  So, you will just have to write that portion of your app in Java code, wrap it inside a `.jar` file, and import into your Delphi code as an external API, per Embarcadero's documentation:

[Using a Custom Set of Java Libraries In Your RAD Studio Android Apps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps)

**Update:** in Seattle, most of the missing methods have now been added to `Jlang_Class`.  However, `getDeclaredMethod()` is not one of them, but fortunately `getDeclaredMethods()` has been added, so you should be able to write a small wrapper for that, eg:

```
function getdeclaredMethod(Cls: Jlang_Class; const Name: JString): JMethod;
var
  Arr: TJavaObjectArray<JMethod>;
  Meth: JMethod;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Arr := Cls.getDeclaredMethods;
  for I := 0 to Arr.Length-1 do
  begin
    Meth := Arr.Items[I];
    if Meth.getName.compareTo(Name) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := Method;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('method not found: %s', [Name]);
end;
```

And then you can do this:

```
function killCall(context: JContext): Boolean;
var
  obj: JObject;
  telephonyManager: JTelephonyManager;
  classTelephony: Jlang_Class;
  methodGetITelephony: JMethod;
  telephonyInterface: JObject;
  telephonyInterfaceClass: Jlang_Class;
  methodEndCall: JMethod;
begin
  try
    // Get the boring old TelephonyManager
    obj := context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager := TJTelephonyManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

    // Get the getITelephony() method
    classTelephony := TJlang_Class.JavaClass.forName(telephonyManager.getClass.getName);
    methodGetITelephony := getDeclaredMethod(classTelephony, StringToJString('getITelephony'));

    // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
    methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(True);

    // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
    telephonyInterface := methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

    // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
    telephonyInterfaceClass := TJlang_Class.JavaClass.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass.getName);
    methodEndCall := getDeclaredMethod(telephonyInterfaceClass, StringToJString('endCall'));

    // Invoke endCall()
    methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

    Result := True;
  except
    on E: Exception do // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
    begin
      //
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The bug was for XE-8. I have DELPHI 10 SEATTLE.

Comment: Have you got some little help for me? I will try if the bug is in DELPHI 10 SEATTLE?

Comment: Actually, the bug has existed since Android was first added to Delphi in XE5. I don't have Seattle installed yet, but the bug does exist in XE8, so it is not a stretch to assume it likely still exists in Seattle, especially since the bug was not reported to QualityPortal until just a few minutes ago (by me) and Embarcadero has deprecated QualityCentral in favor of QualityPortal, so they might not have even seen the original QC bug report yet (that ticket is still open).

Comment: Hello Remy,

on StackOverflow's not my question. Just out of interest, I began to pursue it.
I looked at Delphi library Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes 10 Seattle and [I found a complete declaration Jlang_class with all features](https://forums.embarcadero.com/messageview.jspa?messageID=712894)

I also found a [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105837) to a forum where you answer this question once deal it.
Unfortunately, that link lines are already broken.

Comment: @pudnivec74: If you look more closely, `Jlang_Class` is still missing several methods that are defined in Android's [`Class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) type, including `getDeclaredMethod()`. It does, however, have `getDeclaredMethods()` now, which should be a usable substitute for `getDeclaredMethod()`, by looping through the returned array calling `getName()` on each `JMethod` until the desired method name is found.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your answer. But I have 2 problems: JMethod doesn't support setAccessible and invoke  methods.

Comment: For `JMethod.setAccessible` you must use `JAccessibleObject(JMethod).setAccessible(True)`. In your case `JAccessibleObject(methodGetITelephony).setAccessible(True)`

Comment: On how to replace `invoke` I have not yet come

Comment: Looks like `invoke()` is not available in Delphi yet, so this issue is still unsolvable until Embarcadero fleshes out the JNI Bridge a bit more.

Comment: Is there any possibility this function to bypass or replace?

Comment: You cannot bypass it, the `invoke()` is required. But you *might* be able to declare the `JMethod` interface manually in your own code so you can add the missing `invoke()` method to it. I am not sure as I can't test it myself.